# How to run RediSearch module with Redis on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, redis, path, redisearch

I followed the steps on https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/ and have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and am successfully running Redis v4.09 on Windows. But, when following the steps on https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Quick_Start/, I have some issues.

In the download and running binaries section, I don't understand what I'm supposed to replace `/path/to/module/src/redisearch.so` with. I've downloaded RediSearch for Ubuntu 18.04 and I've moved the files to a folder named RediSearch within my Downloads folder. Could someone help me with the pathing considering I'm using Ubuntu on Windows? I've also tried it with Building and Running with Source section but that just runs into an error every time I run make:

> *** No rule to make target 'build'. Stop.

How can I run the module with Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WSL, you have access to `C:` through `/mnt/c/` from Linux.

So, if you really want to have redisearch on a folder in Downloads you need to use something like:

```
/mnt/c/Users/<yourUser>/Downloads/yourFolder/src/redisearch.so
```

However, you probably should use a folder within Linux instead. You can use [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download from Linux.